# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DataPoint<DateTime>>' of 'function result'

Tags: list, flutter, dart, charts, bezier

I want a chart which showes data of the last week. Therefore, I use bezier_chart. Everything works, but I want the displayed data to be in a list. Instead of putting the data directly in the `data:` (as it is in the tutorial), I gave it directly in the var datatest, but I get an error. The error is: `type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DataPoint<DateTime>>' of 'function result'`.

Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

This is my code in the BezierChart:

```
child: BezierChart(
    fromDate: fromDate,
    bezierChartScale: BezierChartScale.WEEKLY,
    toDate: toDate,
    selectedDate: toDate,
    series: [
       BezierLine(
         label: "Duty",
         onMissingValue: (dateTime) {
           return 0.0;
         },
         data: dataTest,
       ),
```

This is my dataTest list:

```
var dataTest = [
    DataPoint<DateTime>(
        value: 10, xAxis: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2))),
    DataPoint<DateTime>(
        value: 100, xAxis: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3))),
  ];
```

Thsi is the link to the example:
https://pub.dev/packages/bezier_chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
List<DataPoint<DateTime>> dataTest = [
    DataPoint<DateTime>(
        value: 10, xAxis: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 2))),
    DataPoint<DateTime>(
        value: 100, xAxis: DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 3))),
];
```

The problem is that the `data` parameter from the `BezierChart` expects a `List<DataPoint<DateTime>>` but since you're declaring your list as `var List` the compiler will complain that you're not enforcing the type of values that can go into your created list